# How many clients subscribed to a topic using MQTT

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosca

I'm using mqtt.js and mosca. I would like to know how many clients subscribed to a topic. How can i achive this goal?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

At a MQTT protocol level you can not do this, there is no way for a publishing client to know if there are any subscribers to a given topic.

While you probably could implement something with the mosca hooks and callbacks and work out a way to publish the information under the `$sys` topic space, you will still need to not only count clients that have subscribed to the topic explicitly but also matching wildcard subscriptions.

This get's tricky because they only get matched at the point a message is published, so really at best you could only count the number of clients a message was delivered to at the point of publishing. This then ignores any clients with QOS 1/2 subscriptions that are offline at the time of publishing and the message will be queued for.

All in all you need to think why you want this number as it normally goes against the concept of pub/sub messaging for the publisher to care if there are any subscribers.

Comment: I understand, thank you. My first idea was, when a client receive a certain message in that topic he send a message with a status but i don't know if is the right way